# How do I save my the submitted values from settings.php?

Tags: php

So here's the code for settings.php firstly.

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<a href="mainpage.php">Main Page</a>
<a href="tictactoe.php">Game</a>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

<form action="mainpage.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Bio: <input type="text" name="bio"><br>
Hobbies: <input type="text" name="hobbies"><br>
Past School: <input type="text" name="past"><br>
Work History: <input type="text" name="work"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get all the values submitted from this page to the mainpage.php to save so that when I click another one of my links and then come back, it's still there. Here's the code for my mainpage.php

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<a href="settings.php">Settings</a>
<a href="tictactoe.php">Game</a>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST)){

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $bio = $_POST['bio'];
 $hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
 $past = $_POST['past'];
 $work = $_POST['work'];

 echo "<br>";
 echo "My name is: " . $name . "<br />";
 echo "My email is: " . $email . "<br />";
 echo "A bit about myself: " . $bio . "<br />";
 echo "These are my hobbies: " . $hobbies . "<br />";
 echo "These are past school: " . $past . "<br />";
 echo "These are my past work: " . $work . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a very broad topic but I'd start here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)

Comment: maybe using session is one method

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the manual link, http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Plan is to,

1. create database and tables as per your design,
2. establish connection between database
3. add insert query
4. retrive the inserted records from database and display in HTML using php.

Comment: You don't think MySQL might be a little overblown here? SQLite would be easier to get going however I'd be looking at more of a simple key/value persistence. This doesn't look like it requires a relational database

Comment: My thought is, once cleared the browser privacy, the data get empty right, thats why.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<a href="settings.php">Settings</a>
<a href="tictactoe.php">Game</a>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>

<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST)){

 $_SESSION['form_data']['name'] = $name = $_POST['name'];
 $_SESSION['form_data']['email'] = $email = $_POST['email'];
 $_SESSION['form_data']['bio']  = $bio = $_POST['bio'];
 $_SESSION['form_data']['hobbies'] = $hobbies = $_POST['hobbies'];
 $_SESSION['form_data']['past'] = $past = $_POST['past'];
 $_SESSION['form_data']['work'] = $work = $_POST['work'];

} else if(!empty($_SESSION['form_data']) && empty($_POST)){

    $name = $_SESSION['form_data']['name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['form_data']['email'];
    $bio = $_SESSION['form_data']['bio'];
    $hobbies = $_SESSION['form_data']['hobbies'];
    $past = $_POST['past'];
    $work = $_SESSION['form_data']['work'];
}
 echo "<br>";
 echo "My name is: " . $name . "<br />";
 echo "My email is: " . $email . "<br />";
 echo "A bit about myself: " . $bio . "<br />";
 echo "These are my hobbies: " . $hobbies . "<br />";
 echo "These are past school: " . $past . "<br />";
 echo "These are my past work: " . $work . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! had to do minor fixes however :)

Comment: it was untested but good enough for you to get you started!

Answer (score 0):

if this is only one form in your application you can use file based storage without using any database. you can store the form information in a file located in specific folder and then you can store and retrieve your form values from the file. You can refer to this link below
https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/save-php-form-data-to-a-txt-file.757223/